# Setting a default namespace for a namespace manager in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, xpath, xml-namespaces, powershell-5.0

I have the following code which correctly fetches the AD Property links from the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
$uri = 'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx' #lists all AD attributes
$results = [xml](Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials)
[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsMgr = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($results.NameTable)
$nsMgr.AddNamespace('ns','http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
$results.SelectNodes("/ns:html/ns:body/ns:div[@id = 'page']/ns:div[@id = 'body']/ns:div[@id = 'content']/ns:div[@class = 'topic']/ns:div[@id = 'mainSection']/ns:dl/ns:dd/ns:a/@href",$nsMgr)
```

Originally I'd hoped to avoid adding the namespace prefix (`ns:`), which [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx) implies can be done by adding a namespace with the prefix `string.Empty`.  This seems to work in terms of setting the default namespace; but `SelectNodes` does not make use of this default.

```
$uri = 'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx' #lists all AD attributes
$results = [xml](Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials)
[System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsMgr = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($results.NameTable)
#$nsMgr.AddNamespace('ns','http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml') #tried with and without this line
$nsMgr.AddNamespace([string]::Empty,'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
$nsMgr.DefaultNamespace #returns http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml as hoped
$results.SelectNodes("/html",$nsMgr).Name #should return `html` but doesn't (though works if we register the prefix and use /ns:html)
```

### Question:

Is there any way to have PowerShell use `SelectNodes` without requiring a namespace prefix / via setting a default namespace?

Comment: In case it's useful to anyone, this is the resultant script for fetching info on the various AD attributes: https://gist.github.com/JohnLBevan/09021f504247454f0e603587f82bcf58

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, the concept of a default namespace *in the sense of not having to prefix node names with it*:

- applies to XML *documents*
- does *not* apply to *XPath expressions*.

In other words:

- If a document / element subtree declares a default namespaces along the lines of `<foo xmlns='http://example.org'>`, that element and all descendants not using a namespace prefix are *implicitly* in that default namespace.
- By contrast, referring to such nodes in the context of an *XPath expression* requires that you:

  - *choose* a prefix to map the document's default namespace URI to (`ns` in your example)
  - *explicitly use that prefix* to match nodes in the default namespace (e.g., `ns:div`)

The above is supported by the following excerpt from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation?view=netframework-4.7.2) (emphasis added):

> If the XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that the namespace Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is the *empty* namespace. **If your XML includes a default namespace, you must still add a prefix and namespace URI to the XmlNamespaceManager**; otherwise, no nodes will be selected.